# add, delete and sort using array in java

Tags: java

I need to make a code of an employee record.

Here's how it should work:

(1) Display a menu of choices:

a) choice 1 -> add employee 
  a.1) employee name 
  a.2) employee age 
  a.3) employee phone number 
b) choice 2 -> Delete employee record(s)
c) Choice 3 -> Sort employee record alphabetically
(2) If user chooses choice1, the input data is stored in an ARRAY (or ARRAYLIST) until the user chooses to stop inputting data.

Kindly help me. I don't know whether to use multi-dimensional ARRAYS (or ARRAYLIST) for this. Specifically, I don't know how I'm gonna store the STRING (employee name) data with the INTEGER (employee age/phone number) data.

Thank you very, very much in advance!

Additionally, kindly educate me about Parallel Sorting of the data for the Array (Name and phone numbers). I couldn't do it..

Comment: No it is a project. i already tried to search solutions from the internet but i could hardly find the best solution for this project and another thing is that we are not allowed to use ArrayList and the program will merely using array and not with the help of any database languages.

Comment: It is a non-homework project and "we are not allowed to use ArrayList..." What the heck? Are you serious??

Comment: i guess the "boss" said that they can't use arraylist.. .LOL .. :)

Comment: yes i'm not kidding...I already tried to ask if ArrayList will do, but he suggest not to...

Comment: Then it is homework or a test. Please don't lie to us.

Comment: @Rtrack07: it's not a problem asking homework related questions here, but please tag them as such (homework tag).

Answer (score 2):

I would use an ArrayList (or if this is part of a large application that uses a large amount of data, a database). I would store everything in an Employee object, one that holds the employee's name, date of birth (used to calculate age), phone number, etc... Doing this means you don't need to use parallel arrays or ArrayLists.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly homework but you don't appear to have paid much attention in class or read anything about how to program in Java. The biggest problem with trying to help someone who isn't willing to put in the effort is they don't know enough to understand the answer or feel the need to argue with someone trying to help them. :P

The other frustration is that students who don't do the work, are often not even grateful for the help. ;)

> I need to make a code of an employee record.

You should start with a class which represents all the fields the record must hold.

> a) choice 1 -> add employee

You need a collection class. If you can't use ArrayList you have to write your own collection which at least supports add(Employee record)

> a.1) employee name a.2) employee age a.3) employee phone number

These are your three fields.

> b) choice 2 -> Delete employee record(s)

Your collection needs a delete method.

> c) Choice 3 -> Sort employee record alphabetically

I assume this is by name.  I also assume they mean ASCIIbetically as this is simpler. You might want to ask.

> (2) If user chooses choice1, the input data is stored in an ARRAY (or ARRAYLIST) until the user chooses to stop inputting data.

You need an option to stop or quit.

> Kindly help me. I don't know whether to use multi-dimensional ARRAYS (or ARRAYLIST) for this.

I certainly wouldn't  Java is for Object Orientated programming an I suggest you use Objects (your collection could be an array of references to objects)

> Specifically, I don't know how I'm gonna store the STRING (employee name) data with the INTEGER (employee age/phone number) data.

Java is case sensitive, so you might use String but not STRING. I would use `int` not Integer or INTEGER.

> Additionally, kindly educate me about Parallel Sorting of the data for the Array (Name and phone numbers). I couldn't do it..

If you want to know how ArrayList or Collections.sort() works you only have to read the code!

Comment: In spite of your criticism... I still thank you all for your encouraging comments...although your comments are negative, I still thank you for giving your time on commenting on this, that seems to be a homework...thank you guys...I love this page...

Comment: @Rtrack07, I didn't vote to close, but I hope you understand why so many did. You have to demonstrate you are will to make an effort and that it won't be a waste of our time trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i understand that your real problem here is you don't know how to store 2 things together  in 1 array cell(or what unit is it).the solution is : write a class(Employee maybe) that includes all fields that you need and store the that(Employee) object into any data structure you want.

On the other hand , you should check the forums or even some kind of wiki about sorting algorithms. choose what ever fits your "Home Work" and implement it in a method. good luck.